# RDS : Unable to execute HTTP request: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Please refer the following code which I am using to list log files available in RDS ( Mysql )

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXX", "XXX");
AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new StaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);

AmazonRDS rdsClient = AmazonRDSClientBuilder.standard()
.withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("XXXX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306", "us-west-2"))
.withCredentials(provider)
.build();

DescribeDBLogFilesRequest request = new DescribeDBLogFilesRequest();

DescribeDBLogFilesResult response = rdsClient.describeDBLogFiles(request);
List<DescribeDBLogFilesDetails> listOfFiles = response.getDescribeDBLogFiles();

System.out.println(listOfFiles.toString());
System.out.println("Program done");
```

Here is my pom.xml dependencies :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-rds -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-rds</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.101</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am facing exception when using the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
.withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("XXXX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306", "us-west-2"))
```

You're trying to connect to your actual RDS *instance* with the SDK, and that isn't the correct approach.  You need to connect to the [RDS Query API Endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#rds_region).  These requests are sent through the *service*.

You should be able to simply use [`.withRegion()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#withRegion-java.lang.String-), and not have to actually supply the endpoint URL, since the endpoint is the same for all RDS instances within a region, and the default regional URLs are coded into the SDK.